# Add tabbar in Home page in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to develop for my project for firstly coming splash screen after then Home scree. In that home screen contains Tabbar in bottom side. Please suggest any one. How to proceed. I need programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to create a tabbar on a specific view controller:

on ViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *tab;
```

on ViewController.m

```
self.tab = [UITabBarController new];

// FirstViewController
FirstViewController *vc1=[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
vc1.title=@"First View Controller";
vc1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"viewcontroller1.png"];

//SecondViewController
SecondViewController *vc2 = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
vc2.title=@"Second";
vc2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"viewcontroller2.png"];

self.tab.viewControllers = @[vc1, vc2];

[self.view addSubview:self.tab.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a how to create  programatically a tab bar with some navigation controllers in it. But I strongly recommend to use storyboard stead

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    //Alloc all the VC of the tab bar
    UIViewController *firstViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *secondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *thirdViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    //Create the tab bar
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];        

    //Set the array of the tab bar with the VCs
    tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstViewController, secondViewController, thirdViewController];

    //create the navigation controller
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationControlle alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];

    // init the app with the tab bar
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

    //
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I need to write UIViewController class not in appdelegate class

Comment: on a specific view controller? you should specify better your doubts.

Comment: yes, i need to implement specific view controller